# Do i need a license, for parsing a command/program that is not written by myself?

Tags: license

// Example in c++:

```
string cmd1 = "sudo dmidecode";
string cmd2 = "sudo nethogs -t -s -a -d 1";
string cmd3 = "sudo intel_gpu_top -J";

FILE *pipe = popen(cmd1.c_str(), "r");
```

// Example in java:

```
String cmd1 = "sudo dmidecode";
String cmd2 = "sudo nethogs -t -s -a -d 1";
String cmd3 = "sudo intel_gpu_top -J";

ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder();
builder.command("bash","-c",cmd);
                
Process p=null;
if(debugThreadsLow) {System.out.println("execute: "+cmd);}
try {
    p = builder.start();
} catch (IOException e) {e.printStackTrace();return null;}
```

My question is now: do i need to care about the license of dmidecode, intel_gpu_top or nethogs?

(Or include, for each program i parse, the license in my project?)

Comment: To 90%, does this also apply to MIT Licensed programs?

Comment: Answer: 
https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83041/do-i-need-a-license-for-parsing-a-command-programm-that-is-not-written-by-mysel?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C334.4990

Comment: This is now a perfect example of [why we ask people not to cross-post on the Stack Exchange network](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu).